# Get all keys of a deep object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object:

```
var abc = {
    1: "Raggruppamento a 1",
    2: "Raggruppamento a 2",
    3: "Raggruppamento a 3",
    4: "Raggruppamento a 4",
    count: '3',
    counter: {
        count: '3',
    },
    5: {
        test: "Raggruppamento a 1",

        tester: {
            name: "Georgi"
        }
    }
};
```

I would like to retrieve the following result:

- abc[1]
- abc[2]
- abc[3]
- abc[4]
- abc.count
- abc.counter.count
- abc[5]
- abc[5].test
- abc[5].tester
- abc[5].tester.name

is that possible using nodejs maybe with the help of plugins?

Comment: Just FYI, that's not an "array".

Comment: Sorry, just didnt think about it...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this by recursively traversing the object:

```
function getDeepKeys(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for(var key in obj) {
        keys.push(key);
        if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key]);
            keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
                return key + "." + subkey;
            }));
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Running `getDeepKeys(abc)` on the object in your question will return the following array:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "5.test", "5.tester", "5.tester.name", "count", "counter", "counter.count"]
```

Comment: Just found an issue in your example. What happens if they key is a number? example: abc.test[0] - Your example will output abc.test.0 which is wrong.

Comment: @GeorgiK. JavaScript doesn't distinguish between string keys and numeric keys. `test[0]` and `test["0"]` are the same thing. I'm not sure what purpose you're using this code for, why do you need to make this distinction?

Comment: Found this answer through google and adjusted it slightly for my personal need with an added if/else and TypeScript types. Sharing it forward for other googlers like myself: https://paste.ee/p/US30f (paste seeing as code in a comment lacks formatting)

Answer (score 10):

Smaller version, no side effect, just 1 line in function body:

```
function objectDeepKeys(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] instanceof Object).map(key => objectDeepKeys(obj[key]).map(k => `${key}.${k}`)).reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y), Object.keys(obj))
}
```

```js
var abc = {
    1: "Raggruppamento a 1",
    2: "Raggruppamento a 2",
    3: "Raggruppamento a 3",
    4: "Raggruppamento a 4",
    count: '3',
    counter: {
        count: '3',
    },
    5: {
        test: "Raggruppamento a 1",

        tester: {
            name: "Ross"
        }
    }
};

function objectDeepKeys(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => obj[key] instanceof Object)
    .map(key => objectDeepKeys(obj[key]).map(k => `${key}.${k}`))
    .reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y), Object.keys(obj))
}

console.log(objectDeepKeys(abc))
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is bit old post...

This code covers all criteria in JSON object format like just object,object array, nested array object,nested object with array object etc.

```
getDeepKeys = function (obj) {
  var keys = [];
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[key] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key]);
            keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
                return key + "." + subkey;
            }));
        } else if(Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            for(var i=0;i<obj[key].length;i++){
               var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key][i]);
               keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
                return key + "[" + i + "]" + "." + subkey;
               }));
            }
        } else {
          keys.push(key);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I like this because, unlike the accepted answer, it returns the deepest keys instead of all keys:

[
      '1',
      '2',
      '3',
      '4',
      '5.test',
      '5.tester.name',
      'count',
      'counter.count',
     ]

Answer (score 3):

Consider an implementation of `deepKeys` using functional style. We can avoid headaches of mutation, variable reassignment, intermediate assignments, and other side effects -

1. If the input `t` is an object, for each `(k,v)` pair in the object, append `k` to the `path` and recur on the sub-problem, `v`
2. (induction) the input is *not* an object. return the formatted `path`

We can encode this as follows -

```js
const deepKeys = (t, path = []) =>
  Object(t) === t
    ? Object                                             // 1
        .entries(t)
        .flatMap(([k,v]) => deepKeys(v, [...path, k]))
    : [ path.join(".") ]                                 // 2

const input =
  {1:"Raggruppamento a 1",2:"Raggruppamento a 2",3:"Raggruppamento a 3",4:"Raggruppamento a 4",count:'3',counter:{count:'3',},5:{test:"Raggruppamento a 1",tester:{name:"Georgi"}}}

for (const path of deepKeys(input))
  console.log(path)
```

Another great choice to implement this program is JavaScript's generators. Notice the similarity between this `deepKeys` and the implementation above. They both effectively do the same thing -

```js
function* deepKeys (t, path = [])
{ switch(t?.constructor)
  { case Object:
      for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(t))  // 1
        yield* deepKeys(v, [...path, k])
      break
    default:
      yield path.join(".")                    // 2
  }
}

const input =
  {1:"Raggruppamento a 1",2:"Raggruppamento a 2",3:"Raggruppamento a 3",4:"Raggruppamento a 4",count:'3',counter:{count:'3',},5:{test:"Raggruppamento a 1",tester:{name:"Georgi"}}}

for (const path of deepKeys(input))
  console.log(path)
```

Output is the same for each variant of `deepKeys` -

```
1
2
3
4
5.test
5.tester.name
count
counter.count
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code(some fix for previously code from 'Peter Olson', used `lodash`) to get the keys, and check if some of value is `Date`:

```
getDeepKeys = function (obj) {
  let keys = [];
  for (let key in Object.keys(obj)) {
    let value = obj[key];
    if (_.isDate(value)) {
      keys.push(key);
    } else if (_.isObject(value)) {
      let subkeys = getDeepKeys(value);
      keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
        return key + "." + subkey;
      }));
    } else {
      keys.push(key)
    }
  }
  return keys;
}
```

i also checked if value is `mongoDBRef` used condition like this: `((_.isObject(value)) && (value && value.oid))`

Answer (score 0):

```
  getDeepKeys = function (obj) {
var keys = [];
  for(var key in obj) {
      if(typeof obj[key] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key]);
          keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
              return key + "." + subkey;
          }));
      } else if(Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          for(var i=0;i<obj[key].length;i++){
              if ( typeof (obj[key][i]) == "string") {
                 console.log(obj[key][i])
                 keys.push(key)
              }
              else{
                   var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key][i]);
             keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function(subkey) {
              return key + "[" + i + "]" + "." + subkey;
             }));
              }

          }
      } else {
        keys.push(key);
      }
  }
  return keys;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Using recursive function will Help**

```
findKeys = (obj, p) => {

var parent = p
for (let i of Object.keys(obj)) {

  if (typeof (obj[i]) === "object") {
    var k = p + "." + i
    console.log(k)
    this.findKeys(obj[i], k)
  } else {
    console.log(parent + "." + i)
  }
}

 findKeys(abc,"abc")`
```