# Get SubKeys of Json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this code, but it doesn't prints subkeys....

```
    for (var key in result) {
        if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
        var obj = result[key];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
            alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
        }
    }
```

When is an object print: someKey[Object object]

my result (example):

`[ { "branch_id": 992, "sale_id": 24422, "identifier": "", "emitter": { "id": 68, "tax_id": "", "address": { "street": "Carretera a buenavista km 21", "country_code": "MEX", } } } ]`

Comment: please add `result` as well.

Comment: `alert` will not show that level of detail, you should be using `console.log`

Comment: @ninaScholz [
  {
    "branch_id": 992,
    "sale_id": 24422,
    "identifier": "",
    "emitter": {
      "id": 68,
      "tax_id": "",
      "address": {
        "street": "Carretera a buenavista km 21",
        "country_code": "MEX",
      }
}
}
]

Comment: Use `console.log(prop, '=', obj[props])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here.

[Get all keys of a deep object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674473/get-all-keys-of-a-deep-object-in-javascript)

```js
function getDeepKeys(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        keys.push(key);
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            var subkeys = getDeepKeys(obj[key]);
            keys = keys.concat(subkeys.map(function (subkey) {
                return key + "." + subkey;
            }));
        }
    }
    return keys;
} 
var data = [{ "branch_id": 992, "sale_id": 24422, "identifier": "", "emitter": { "id": 68, "tax_id": "", "address": { "street": "Carretera a buenavista km 21", "country_code": "MEX", } } }];

console.log(getDeepKeys(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you handle your function as recursive function instead nested `for in` statements, so you only need to verify if your `value` if an object to recall the function again, so in code you have this:

```js
var json = {
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2",
 "key3": {
   "sub_1_key1": "subvalue1",
    "sub_1_key2": "subvalue2",
    "sub_1_key3": "subvalue3",
    "sub_1_key4": {
     "sub_2_key1": "sub_2_value1"
    }
  },
};

var logger = document.getElementById('logs');

function goThroughJSON(json) {
 for (var attr in json) {
   var value = json[attr];
   if (typeof value === 'object' && !(attr instanceof Array)) {
     return goThroughJSON(value);
    }
    logger.innerHTML += attr + '<br>'
  }
}

goThroughJSON(json);
```

```html
<div id="logs"></div>
```

I really hope you find it helful.

Comment: So you only need the nested key names?

Comment: I need all the names of the main and secondary keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive approach. For any key, if it contains an object value, you can once again call the same function again.

```js
const data = [{ "branch_id": 992, "sale_id": 24422, "identifier": "", "emitter": { "id": 68, "tax_id": "", "address": { "street": "Carretera a buenavista km 21", "country_code": "MEX", } } } ];

const ObjectKey = o => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    if(typeof o[k] === 'object'){
      ObjectKey(o[k]);
    } else {
      console.log(k, " ", o[k]);
    }
  });
}

data.forEach(o => {
  ObjectKey(o);
});
```

Comment: I need all the names of the main and secondary keys.